# xmlstarlet with namespaces attribute replacement

Tags: namespaces, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet

I can't replace an attribute with xmlstarlet.

dog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit    http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd">
<rabbit:connection-factory id="mqConnectionFactory"
host="localhost"
port="9999" />
</beans>
```

Many variations of the following have been tried:

```
xmlstarlet ed -N B="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" -N R="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit" --update "/B/R:connection-factor/@host"  --value "myserver" dog.xml
```

What am I missing? I've tried beans and B:beans for B and many variations of R, but I don't see to be selecting the right element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways around the problem with `failed to load external entity` with your example:

```
xmlstarlet edit --update "//@host" --value "myserver" file.xml
```

or

```
xmlstarlet edit --update "//*[local-name()='connection-factory']/@host" --value "myserver" file.xml
```

Comment: I still wonder about the full path method, but this solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

With full namespace declarations,

```shell
xmlstarlet ed \
    -N B="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" \
    -N rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit" \
    --update '/B:beans/rabbit:connection-factory/@host' \
    --value "myserver" dog.xml
```

or, with an `xmlstarlet` shortcut, per the
[user guide](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html):

```
xmlstarlet ed \
    -N rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit" \
    --update '/_:beans/rabbit:connection-factory/@host' \
    --value "myserver" dog.xml
```

Spot the typo: your command is missing
the final `y` in `connection-factory`.